# How to Store Permalink to Post Authored by User in His Meta Data - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

Here is the situation.

I have a custom post type, let's call it "Listings." I have numerous authors, each of whom has exactly one post of type "Listings." No more, no less.

I want a custom field, let's call it "listing_link", where the link to each author's "Listings" post is stored. I would like this to be generated automatically.

So essentially I need some kind of function that will:

**1.** Cycle through each author

**2.** Find all posts of type "Listings" by that author

**3.** Get the permalink to the first (and only) post of that type by that author

**4.** Finally save that link in a custom field I've created

I could code bits of this, but I'm really not sure where to start. When/how would this function run? How would it refresh? How do you actually save it to their meta data?

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's not a full script. I really just need to be sent in the right direction! If I can come up with a functioning solution, I will share it with the community!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to store 'listing-link'? Why not just query "listings" when you need the information?